# Hibernate with oracle dblink implementation

Tags: hibernate, dblink

Just new with hibernate, is there a way to implement oracle dblink on hibernate? e.g. `select * from tablename@dblink` to be used in hql?

Answer (score 4):

Creating a SYNONYM in Oracle for tablename@dblink and configuring your Hibernate entity to map this synonym should do the trick.