# Use Hibernate to access an Oracle DBLink'ed table

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, dblink

My user wants to input random sql to access databases for which a db link exists in `Oracle` db. However, this gives an exception with `Hibernate`.
Below is a function which is supposed to check whether the query is valid by running the query.
Any recommendation is welcome.

The exception is:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query 'Select ID,NAME from YYY@XXX_DB_LINK'
```

Here is the code:

```
public String testSQL(String sqlQuery) {
    if(!checkAllowedSQL(sqlQuery)) {
        logger.debug("Forbidden SQL Query detected: " + sqlQuery);
        return "Forbidden SQL Query detected '" + sqlQuery + "'";
    }


try {
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery);
        List<Object[]> list = query.getResultList();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return e.toString() +  " '" + sqlQuery + "'";
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: nice question but I suppose is same as this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017108/hibernate-with-oracle-dblink-implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a `SYNONYM` for your linked table `YYY@XXX_DB_LINK`, then your user can submit a native query like `Select ID,NAME from YYY`without worrying about table real location.